# How to write Hadoop Compression/Decompression codec for LZMA2?

Tags: hadoop, codec, compression, lzma

I want to write an Hadoop decompression codec for LZMA2 that can read .xz files.
This is my assignment and I am totally new to Compression or Decompression codec.
I am seeking some guidance on this issue.From where I should start and where I will get corresponding help for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement the [CompressionCodec](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/CompressionCodec.html) interface as well as Compressor and Decompressor for LZMA2. You can look at the GzipCodec code in Hadoop for an example of how to do this.